# How to use styled-components that extends from an already styled component?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styled-components

I'm trying to extract all my component styling using styled-component to a single file.

However, I am running into an error where if I extract the styling and the component which the styling is reliant into a separate file, the themes stop working.

**Button.jsx**

```
import {ButtonWrapper} from './Button.styled';
import {Button as MUButton} from '@material-ui/core/Button';

export const Button = () => {
  return <ButtonWrapper>
    <Button/>
  </ButtonWrapper>
}
```

**SmallButton.jsx**

```
import {StyledSmallButton} from './Button.styled';

// import {Button} from './Button'

// const StyledSmallButton = styled(Button)` // This works.
//   width: 50%
// `

export const SmallButton = () => {
  return <StyledSmallButton/>
}
```

**Button.styled.jsx**

```
import {Button} from './Button';

export const ButtonWrapper = styled.div`
  width: 100%
`;

export const StyledSmallButton = styled(Button)` //Doesn't work.
  width: 50%
`;
```

**Error**

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot create styled-component for component: undefined
```

I believe there is a cyclic dependency problem here i.e. `SmallButton` requires `Button` which is themed by `ButtonWrapper`.
How can I solve this?

Comment: Also, just a word of warning, when restyling a styled component, be sure to pass through `className` as a prop, or your styles won't work

Answer (score 0):

I think you've imported the MUButton wrong. Should the `<Button />` component actually be `<MUButton />`?

```
import {ButtonWrapper} from './Button.styled';
import {Button as MUButton} from '@material-ui/core/Button';
                 // ^ this is the alias

export const Button = ({ className }) => {
  return <ButtonWrapper>
    <MUButton className={className} />
     // ^ This should be MUButton
  </ButtonWrapper>
}
```

Edit: passed the className prop down as mentioned by Andy int he comments